# How to calculate the value of $z^{752}$ in exponential form, where $z$ is a complex number (beginner’s question)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to calculate $z^{752}$ in exponential form, where $z = \sqrt{3} − i$.

Is this task simply a matter of setting up an expression in the form of $z = re^{i\theta}$ and raising this to the exponent of $752$, or have I misunderstood the task?

Comment: Nope, that's it. You might possibly convert your answer back to cartesian form too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s what’s wanted, but with final simplification, also.

You can see that
$$
z=2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-i\frac{1}{2}\right)=2e^{-i\pi/6}
$$
Now, $752=62\cdot12+8$ and so
$$
-i\frac{\pi}{6}\cdot 752=…
$$

Comment: I interpret that you have rearranged 752 into multiples of 12 so that we can have two expressions, one with e^(2*π*-i) and the other with the remainder. If i recall correctly, there was a nice little identity where e^(2*π*-i) had a significant value, perhaps it was i^i... am i on the right track?

Comment: seems that the value of that expressions is actually 1, so then the final simplified result should be 124*e^((4*pi*-i)/3)

Comment: @doom01 The modulus is $2^{752}$ (which I wouldn't try and write otherwise); the argument of the number is indeed $-\frac{4}{3}\pi i$ and you can compute easily $e^{-4\pi i/3}$, can't you?

Comment: e−4πi/3e−4πi/3 = (-1)^(2/3). Im sorry, but i dont understand why you mentioned the modulus 2^752. Nevertheless, I am quite happy with the amount of help you have given me. At this point the problem has been reduced to a point where I can ask people at uni about my arithmetic. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As $2^{752}=4\cdot (1.024)^{75}\cdot 10^{225}$ this would be a rather long number to write down.